# How to implement a next button for a forum in php?

Tags: php, moodle

Currently trying to implement a next button that would take you to the next topic in a forum but I have no idea where to start.

Assuming the forum is constantly updated in terms of the time of the last post.

Comment: What did you try? We can't help you without any effort on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they have an autoincrementing primary key in the database, you could get the current ID, bump it and create a link pointing to the next one (provided you do a quick check to make sure its valid, e.g., the next post wasn't deleted previously).

EDIT: If the forums are sorted by last update (and you want the "next" post to mean the next most recently updated, then you'll need to do a little querying.

```
$sql = "SELECT postID, postName FROM forum_posts WHERE last_updated < '$thisPostsLastUpdate' ORDER BY last_updated DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query( $dbconn , $sql );
$fetch = $result->fetch_array();
```

$fetch should contain the array of values you want (the ID for generating a link to the next post and postName as the link's text).